# Ubuntu 14.04 Ubuntu Software center does not start

Tags: 14.04, software-center

I installed Ubuntu 14.04. The Ubuntu Software icon on the launch panel does not launch the program. The cursor is busy for a while - then nothing happens.
I cannot add new programs.
I am a new Ubuntu user, what should I do?

Comment: Open a terminal window, run the `software-center` command, and let us know the output by editing your question.

Comment: it said the program is not currently installed.

Comment: said also "sudo apt install software-center", I did it.  Did not help any!

Comment: Try to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Press the "Windows" aka Dash Key and type: `Ubuntu Software Center`, press 
`ENTER`

or open a Terminal: `CTRL+ALT+T`
and type: `software-center` press `ENTER`

Comment: OK, I can access software-center that way! When I search software-center from there it shows that I have it installed twice! At least two icons comes with a "right sign". Shoul I try to remove the other one?

Comment: Actually the other icon just dissapeared by it self.